# MacOS app run Applescript to execute keystroke on other application

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a question about running applescript in MacOS app.

I would like to create a Mac App and it can execute an Applescript to copy the selected text on Chrome.

Here is the Applescript:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    try
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "c" using {command down}
        end tell
    on error
        display dialog "error" buttons {"OK"}
    end try
end tell

delay 1
set selectedText to the clipboard
```

The idea is I save this Applescript in the distributed Mac App and let the app to execute this script.

In development env *(before compiled to {Appname}.app)*, it can successfully switch to Chrome and copy the selected text.

However, after bundling it as an {Appname}.app, it can activate Chrome if it has not run yet, but it cannot execute the `Command + C` keyboard combination.

My guess is the app didn't ask the `Accessibility in Security Setting`, so I add it and turn it on. But it still can't work.

I've also tried to add the `entitlement` setting, but still failed:

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
<array>
   <string>com.google.Chrome</string>
   <string>com.apple.systemevents</string>
</array>
```

Does anyone know the possible solution?

I am the newbie of Mac App development. Any hint is very welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chrome actually has a copy selection command.  No need to bring system events into the equation.

```
if application "Google Chrome" is running then
    set the clipboard to ""
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        tell active tab of window 1
            copy selection
        end tell
    end tell
    set selectedText to the clipboard
end if
```

Or you can just insert this following handler into your code (I prefer adding mine towards the bottom of my script)

```
to copySelection(theApp)
    set the clipboard to ""
    activate application theApp
    repeat while application theApp is not frontmost
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process theApp
            keystroke "c" using {command down}
        end tell
    end tell
    set selectedText to (the clipboard)
end copySelection
```

Then anytime you want to run that handler, just call it by using this line of code (inserting the application name instead of my example of TextEdit)

```
copySelection("TextEdit") -- Replace With Your Desired App
```